# jQuery Mobile redraws entire screen on page change on Jelly bean

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, transition, flicker

I know there are **a lot** of questions about flickering jQuery Mobile, but none of the "fixes" I have found have worked for me. My problem only occurs on Jelly bean, not on Android 2.3.6.

---

I have a multi page app using jQuery Mobile 1.2.0, jQuery 1.8.2 and Cordova 2.3.0. For the sake of testing I have created a simple HTML layout with only 3 empty pages, each of them containing a persistent fixed navbar at the top, with 3 "tabs" to switch between the pages.

On my Nexus One running Android 2.3.6 things work perfectly, no flickering when switching between pages. The pages just appear, and the tabs stay in place and just switch color.

On my Samsung Galaxy S3 mini running Android 4.1.1 on the other hand, there's a problem. When switching between pages, the entire screen seems to be redrawn, including the navbar. This causes a flicker for just a microsecond, during which the entire screen seems to be the dark color of the default background gradient of jQuery Mobile's theme A (the flicker is less pronounced when looking at the bottom of the screen). Since this is only happening on Jelly bean, there's got to be some way of fixing this, right?

As you can see from the code below, I have turned of page transitions.

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>  
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./jquery/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="jquery_init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="./jquery/jquery.mobile-1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>    

    <style>
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div data-role="page" id="page1" data-position="fixed"data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="topbar" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h1>JQTest</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">
        <h1>This is Page 1</h1>                
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->


  <div data-role="page" id="page2" data-position="fixed"data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="topbar" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h1>JQTest</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">                
        <h1>This is Page 2</h1>                
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->


  <div data-role="page" id="page3" data-position="fixed"data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" data-id="topbar" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h1>JQTest</h1>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#page1">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page2">Page 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#page3" class="ui-btn-active ui-state-persist">Page 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /navbar -->
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content">                
        <h1>This is Page 3</h1>                
    </div><!-- /content -->
  </div><!-- /page -->



</body>
</html>
```

**jquery_init.js**

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = 'none';
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = 'none';
    $.mobile.buttonMarkup.hoverDelay = 0;
});
```

---

**EDIT**

Upon further testing, it seems that it is an element of the `ui-overlay-a` class that is being displayed during the flickering. Setting it's background color to red produces a red flickering that covers the entire screen when changing pages.

Comment: Did you fix this? If you remove all the "data-positon='fixed'" attributes, does it go away?

Comment: I am also facing same issue, is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed `data-position="fixed"` from the `header & footer` and added these styles to all the input controls(`textarea`,`select dropdowns`,etc) :

```
[selector] input,[selector] select{   
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    appearance:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: none;
}

Since data-position="fixed" is removed from the header & footer section, we need to fix the styles by adding this:

[data-role="header"],[data-role="footer"]{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

Worked for my page!!
```